# not able to get another page when iam using python request session module to login

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to login LinkedIn using python request session module but iam not able access other pages please help me out.
My code is like this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get login form 
URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
session = requests.session()
login_response = session.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login')
login = BeautifulSoup(login_response.text,"lxml")

# Get hidden form inputs
inputs = login.find('form', {'name': 'login'}).findAll('input', 
{'type': 
['hidden', 'submit']})

# Create POST data
post = {input.get('name'): input.get('value') for input in inputs}
post['session_key'] = 'usename'
post['session_password'] = 'password'

# Post login
post_response = session.post('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-
submit', data=post)

notify_response = session.get('https://www.linkedin.com/company-
beta/3067/')
notify = BeautifulSoup(notify_response.text,"lxml")

print notify.title
```

Comment: Why don't you use the LinkedIn [API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api#)?

Comment: How it could be used iam new to this by the way can i scrap all the page with that?i dont think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, hope I'm not saying wrong stuff, but I had to crawl linkedin some weeks ago and seen linkedin is pretty good at spoting bots. I'm almost sure it is your issue here (you should try to print output of `post_response`, you surelly you will see you are on a captcha page or something like that).

**Plot twist**: I succeed to login into linkedin by running selenium, login to linkedin by hand and use `pickle` to save cookies as text file.

Then, instead of using login form, I just loaded cookies to selenium and refresh page, tadam, logged in. I think this can be done with `requests`